# Error when running "flutter pub get" in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: flutter

when I run "flutter pub get" I receiving this error message:

**Cannot open file, path = '.packages' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13) Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_erp...                pub get failed (66; Cannot open file, path = '.packages' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13))**

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTH7L.png)

I have installed flutter via snap. "flutter doctor" command gives the following result given in screen shot.

[flutter doctor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCqQb.png)

Comment: You better  manually install flutter instead of using snap. There are too much issues with flutter snap.

Answer (score -1):

Try to fix it with this command `sudo chown -R $USER /opt/flutter`.

Maybe you don't have the correct permissions.

Comment: flutter directory is not under '/opt', it is located into '/home' directory and i have already given ownership for the current user.